# How to access GET parameters in mod_rewrite RewriteCond?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to access GET parameters from mod_rewrite.

E.g., given this URL: http://myserver.com/foo.png?foo=bar

The following rule does not catch this URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} bar [NC]
```

While this one does:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} bar [NC]
```

Doesn't REQUEST_URI include GET parameters? Is THE_REQUEST the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `THE_REQUEST` is the way to go as it will contain the entire http request with the following stipulation:

```
THE_REQUEST
The full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g., "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1"). This does not include any additional headers sent by the browser.
```

- [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: I looked at the documentation, but I interpreted it to mean REQUEST_URI would contain the GET parameters. Oh well.